# How to determine current mozc input mode in bash (command line)?

Tags: bash, keyboard-layout

I'm using `ibus-mozc` and trying to determine which input method is currently set: `Direct Input` or `Hiragana`. Is it possible to determine it via command line?

Any workarounds also will be helpful

For example if it possible to determine what will be printed `a` or `あ` on key press (of course without actual printing) it is also okay